# Floating point maxing out loop doesn't terminate in D, works in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, d

I have two similar programs one in C++ and another in D.

The compilation is on on Windows7 64bit, to 64bit binaries.

C++ version, VS 2013:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float eps = 1.0f;
    float f = 0.0f;
    while (f + eps != f)
        f += 1.0f;

    std::cout << "eps = " + std::to_string(eps) + ", max_f = " + std::to_string(f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

D version, DMD v2.066.1:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

int main(string[] argv)
{
    float eps = 1.0f;
    float f = 0.0f;
    while (f + eps != f)
        f += 1.0f;

    writeln("eps = " ~ to!string(eps) ~ ", max_f = " ~ to!string(f));
    return 0;
}
```

C++ version works as expected and finds that f + e == f when f = 16777216.

But D version hungs forever. When I put breakpoint I see that in D version f also 16777216 (after running for some time) and Watch window (I use VisualD) shows that (f + e != f) is 'false' so the loop should be terminate but it's not the case during runtime.

I think assembly could give the answer but I'm not very good with it.

I'm new to D, so it should be the case that I misused the language/compiler (compiled with DMD just as 'dmd test.d' without additional options and also from VS with VisualD with default options). Any ideas what could be wrong with D version of the program? Thanks!

Disassembly:

C++:

```
000000013F7D1410  mov         rax,rsp  
000000013F7D1413  push        rbp  
000000013F7D1414  lea         rbp,[rax-5Fh]  
000000013F7D1418  sub         rsp,0E0h  
000000013F7D141F  mov         qword ptr [rbp+17h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh  
000000013F7D1427  mov         qword ptr [rax+8],rbx  
000000013F7D142B  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-18h],xmm6  
000000013F7D142F  xorps       xmm1,xmm1  
    float eps = 1.0f;
    float f = 0.0f;
000000013F7D1432  movss       xmm6,dword ptr [__real@3f800000 (013F7D67E8h)]  
000000013F7D143A  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
        f += 1.0f;
000000013F7D1440  addss       xmm1,xmm6  
    while (f + eps != f)
000000013F7D1444  movaps      xmm0,xmm1  
000000013F7D1447  addss       xmm0,xmm6  
000000013F7D144B  ucomiss     xmm0,xmm1  
000000013F7D144E  jp          main+30h (013F7D1440h)  
000000013F7D1450  jne         main+30h (013F7D1440h)
```

D:

```
000000013F761002  mov         ebp,esp  
000000013F761004  sub         rsp,50h  
{
    float eps = 1.0f;
000000013F761008  xor         eax,eax  
000000013F76100A  mov         dword ptr [rbp-50h],eax  
000000013F76100D  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [rbp-50h]  
000000013F761012  movss       dword ptr [f],xmm0  
    float f = 0.0f;
    while (f + eps != f)
        f += 1.0f;
000000013F761017  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR+1138h (013F7C3040h)]  
000000013F76101F  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [f]  
000000013F761024  addss       xmm2,xmm1  
000000013F761028  movss       dword ptr [f],xmm2  
000000013F76102D  fld         dword ptr [f]  
000000013F761030  fadd        dword ptr [__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR+1138h (013F7C3040h)]  
000000013F761036  fld         dword ptr [f]  
000000013F761039  fucomip     st,st(1)  
000000013F76103B  fstp        st(0)  
000000013F76103D  jne         D main+17h (013F761017h)  
000000013F76103F  jp          D main+17h (013F761017h)
```

#### Summary

Accept harold's answer that program behavior is due to the mixed FPU and SSE usage.

Here's a summary what happens in D assembly snippet. In fact the loop will run forever.

SSE behaves strictly according to IEEE-754 when f reaches 16777216.0 and we add 1.0 to this value (f += 1.0f) we still obtain  16777216.0 in xmm2 register, then we store it to memory.

(f + eps != f) expression is computed on the FPU. Since FPU registers have enough precision (f+eps) results in 16777217.0. If we stored this result back to memory into float variable then we would get expected value 16777216.0 (since 16777217.0 is not represented as float). And (f + eps != f) would be 'false' and loop would terminate. But we do not store any numbers back to memory and perform comparison  on the FPU (since we have both operands). It means that we compare one number that is computed strictly according to IEEE-754 (f) and another that is computed with 80bit accuracy (f+eps). 16777216.0 != 16777217.0 and the loop runs forever.

I'm not an expert in this area but for me it looks like that doing floating point with SSE instructions is more robust as was demonstrated in C++ version of the program.

#### Update

I had a discussion on the D forum http://forum.dlang.org/thread/ucnayusylmpvkpcnbhgh@forum.dlang.org

It turned out that program behaves correctly - it's according to the language specification that intermediate calculations can be performed with higher accuracy.

The robust implementation for any D compiler is:

```
import std.stdio;
int main()
{
    const float eps = 1.0f;
    const float step = 1.0;

    float f = 0.0f;
    float fPlusEps = f + eps;
    while (f != fPlusEps)
    {
        f += step;
        fPlusEps = f + eps;
    }
    writeln("eps = ", eps, ", max_f = ", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might have something to do with optimization and floating point math compiler options. Try playing around with them? Also try to write the loop in different ways (just to make sure any optimization doesn't break it).

Comment: Yes, maybe dmd has some different floating point defaults than VC but I performed very simple operations and expected that this will work the same as in C++.

Comment: Show the disassembly. In particular, is one of them really using float sized floats while the other is using 80bit extended precision? It would take a long time (not forever, but too long) to break out of that loop with 80bit extended precision.

Comment: Just few more notes. I'm testing here agains IEEE-754 specification. It should work correctly for any implementation. 80 bit conversion it's only impementation details of x86. When we got results back in memory it should be according to specification. I don't think we should think much about such low level details. And yes, I agree we should never compare results FP computations with == or != but in this case I'm testing floating points behavior according to IEEE-754, so I believe it's valid for this case.

Comment: Unfortunately compilers often don't work that way, and they'll go ahead and use 80bit precision without the extra steps needed to chop the result back its proper precision. As you say, it should be according to the specification when you get it back in memory, but you probably don't get it back in memory, it probably stays in a register as an optimization. Anyway this is easy to check: see the disassembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixed FPU and SSE code, that's .. really strange. I see absolutely no reason to implement it this way.

But they have, and the result is that `f + eps != f` is evaluated with 80bit extended precision, while
`f += 1.0f` is evaluated using 32bit floats.

That means the loop can never end, since `f` will stop going up before the value that makes
`f + eps != f` false (which, in 80bit precision, is huge) is reached.

Comment: Thansk for checking the assembly!. I'll check if I can do something with DMD compiler. Another option is to compile with GDC.

Comment: I figured out that the loop runs forever - it stucks with the same values for each iteration. I updated the question with more detailed explanation of the assembly snippet.

Comment: Compiling with GDC or LDC yields the expected result. As explained in the answer, the cause is the 80-bit precision. The way DMD does it's codegen is rather special, the backend is originally from Digital Mars C, and it was designed to compile code fast, rather than with the maximum final performance.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to break a loop with != or == with floating point values is looking for troubles.

The different behavior is mot likely due to the float to double to 80-bits internal floating point conversion compiler may adopt when passing values to the FPU.

When extending the mantissa, in particular- some compilers or optimizer can decide to let the less significant bit "random" instead of zeroed. So `1.0f`, when given to the FPU may become `1.000000000000000000000012134432` that -according to a `float`- precision, is still `1.0`, but wen `1.000000000000000000000012134432` and `1.000000000000000000000089544455` (the two tail are random) are compared by the FPU, look different.

You should verify how C++ and D compiler treat the floating point extension/reduction and eventually configure the appropriate switches: if the two compilers are not from the same manufacturer, thay had probably made different choices for their respective defaults.

Comment: Ok, my next step is to check compiler options. 

Talking about mantisa extension: as I know comparison for float/double with the same binary presentation in memory should always work, even if FPU internally did some crazy stuff when extending to 80 bit. ie, a = 1.0, b = 1.0, a == b - always tru. Another example, I expect that x/x == 1.0 because it's according to IEEE-754 specification.

Comment: Converting 1 to 1.000000000000000000000012134432 is downright evil. Why would anyone ever do that? That's more trouble than keeping it at 1.

Comment: @harold: To make the code run faster: the FPU use internally 80 bit representaion. If you provide less, and don't reset the tail you need less communication bandwidth between CPU and FPU. It doesn't have much sense in understanding if if has more or less trouble: if you do a sequence of FADD and FMUL, you will in any case, sooner or later, abandon the "exact result arena". It is using == (or !=) the real "trouble".  If I have to design a new language nowadays, I'll deny `==` for floating points.   (And write an article titled "`==` considered harmful")

Comment: Floating point works correctly for integer values until some maximum value (and I try to find it in the above code). Up to that limit addition, multiplication, subrraction and exact comparison should work correctly and produce exactly integer values (i.e. zero after floating point). That's how integer arithmetic works in JavaScript without any issues which uses doubles for all numerical calculations.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia you can't not reset the tail. Instructions that load floating point numbers do that automatically.

Comment: @ArtemKharytoniuk: Are you really intentionally pulling JavaScript into the D-vs-C++ discussion? JavaScript isn't even considered "native" language (loosely speaking of course, as there's no such thing), not to mention that in JavaScript `(0 == "")` and `undefined == null` are `true`, so maybe let's not consider its `123.55 == "    123.55    "` and floating point arithmetic issues.. If you want to compare, take and compare two languages that have **very similar** specs in that region. D/C++ sounds reasonable comparison though.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, I don't care about JS at all;) I just assumsed that some JS implementations use native 'double' for its numeric type. In any case this question about simple program in C++ and D.

Comment: @harold: " Instructions that load floating point numbers do that automatically": depend on the instructions used!

Comment: @ArtemKharytoniuk: There is no such thing named "native double". There are variuos IEE754 formats. Wich is "native" depends on the FPU hardware, not langauge that use it. The way to use it may differ depending on language specs and compiler optimizations. Extending a mantissa, as per IEEE specs (the only authority, here, since it is their own format) can be done by adding random bits, since IEEE does not require for them any particular combination...

Comment: The FPU native format is the 80-bit, since that is the format used by the  X86 FPU electornics (that's the "patform", by judjing from the question) to perform the operations.  Some language impose the 0-filling, other don't impose it. Compilers can be instructed to do one thing or the other.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia well which one doesn't? Ok `fld m80fp`, but it overwrites the tail with actual data.

Comment: @harold: The "actual data" can be random, if the variable you read is shorter. It's the way 32 bit are extended into 80 that makes the difference.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia it certainly can't be random for `fld m80fp`, by definition the tail is taken from that `m80fp`. That's what an `m80fp` operand means. I'm certain `fld m32fp` can't give you random bits in the significand either but I haven't found a proper thing to quote yet.

Comment: A compiler that puts garbage in the low bits of a floating-point number is a broken compiler.  No compiler has ever done that.

Comment: @tmyklebu: That's only your personal opinion (and even a logical nonsense: just do a sematic analysis on your proposition!). There are pre-iso C++ and C compilers that did it. The fact no one does it does not mean it is not permitted. IEEE is the one and only authority that can say what an FP can or cannot do. And they don't say "mantissa extensions must be zeroed". It's just a common practice, not a requirement.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Go read the IEEE standard and tell me where it says arithmetic on floating-point numbers is permitted to produce garbage results.  Then tell me where the C or C++ standards say a strict implementation of the IEEE standard is required.  Then tell me which compilers actually implement the C or C++ standards, especially as they pertain to floating-point math.  Inserting garbage into the significand of a floating-point number is a heinous sin that will break a lot of carefully-written code, which is why compilers don't and have never done that.

Comment: @tmyklebu: The problem is not that "they say you can". They **"don't say you cannot"**. And from that on, your logic becomes nonsensical: I cannot show you something that don't exist!. C++ standard  **dosn't say** that a mantissa must extend with zero. The same is D. (that indeed specifies operation being done on the native FPU format)   To zero or not to zero is an implemetor choice, but doing one thing or the other is perfectly legitimate (and you cannot say "this is broken and the other not).

Comment: Relying on equality in comparing floating point will give implementation dependent results. Unless a specific language defines its own behavior and impose it to implementors. But **that's not the case for D!**, and there is where the different behavior come from